# Using R to combine only "new" timeseries observations between 2 datasets

Tags: r, compare, time-series

Using a separate program, I am collecting timeseries observations every 5 minutes and then generating a CSV file every 5 minutes that includes all 5 minute observations for the current month.  I am trying to figure out, in R program, how to combine "only the new" data from the CSV file into an existing multiyear timeseries database that already contains some of the data from the current month.  I do not want to overwrite the existing data that was already there, I just want to add whatever new timeseries observations there were in the file to the main database.  (Note: the new data may not always be the last line of data in the new file.)  I need some type of script that compares the two files and then adds what is new.  Headers are the same in both files.  I have tried append and merge but can't see to get that to work correctly.  I would appreciate any help!!!!!

```
Monthly Data
DF[1:10,1:10]
             Date.Time PD0Binary PAR NitrateUM NitrateMGL Nlight Ndark Temp2m SpC2m Depth2m
1  2013-05-01 11:40:00        NA  NA        NA         NA     NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
2  2013-05-01 11:45:00        NA  NA        NA         NA     NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
3  2013-05-01 11:50:00        NA  NA        NA         NA     NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
4  2013-05-01 11:55:00        NA  NA        NA         NA     NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
5  2013-05-01 12:00:00        NA  NA        NA         NA     NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
6  2013-05-01 12:05:00        NA  NA        NA         NA     NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
7  2013-05-01 12:10:00        NA  NA        NA         NA     NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
8  2013-05-01 12:15:00        NA  NA        NA         NA     NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
9  2013-05-01 12:20:00        NA  NA        NA         NA     NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
10 2013-05-01 12:25:00        NA  NA        NA         NA     NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
```

Comment: Could you please provide a (small) sample of your collected CSV data?

Comment: Ottel142, would you like raw csv or after being read into R and some processing in how some processing in R before trying to combine it into the main database? My steps in R are **1)** read.csv('Realtime_monthly.csv', header=F, skip=4), **2)**names(DF) <- names(H1), and **3) DF <- transform(DF,Date.Time = as.POSIXct(Date.Time, format="%m/%d/%Y %r")).

Comment: After being read into R + some processing example should be fine.

Comment: Not sure how to display a table in the forum, but here are 3 rows and 3 columns (DF[1:3,1:3])  Date.Time PD0Binary PAR 1 2013-05-01 11:40:00 NA NA 2 2013-05-01 11:45:00 NA NA 3 2013-05-01 11:50:00 NA NA

Comment: You can edit your question and indent each line of your example by 4 spaces to make it a code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information you provided I'd suggest the following solution.

Assuming we have two CSV files. The old one (e.g. containing 120 entries) and the new CSV file (for example with 135 entries) from which we only want to extract the 15 new entries.

1. Use `max(...)`to find the latest Date.Time. Here's an example of how `max` works with Date-time:

   ```
   lastEntry <- max(as.POSIXct("2013-05-23 11:20:00"), as.POSIXct("2013-05-23 11:30:00"),
                    as.POSIXct("2013-05-23 11:25:00"))
   lastEntry
   > [1] "2013-05-23 11:30:00 CEST"
   ```
2. Create a subset of your data from the new CSV file with condition `Date.Time > lastEntry`

   ```
   newEntries <- subset(newCSVdata, Date.Time > lastEntry)
   ```
3. `newEntries` now contains the 15 new entries. Add them to your database.

Comment: Great solution ottel142! The max command I used was 'lastEntry <- max(D2$date.time)'

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Wasn't sure which type your date-time field was, so I've provided an example which parses from string. If you're satisfied with this solution you can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Though, I am not sure why after I rbinded the two datasets, the row numbers are not sequential.  Any ideas? This was the result: 143778 2013-05-20 15:15:00
551710 2013-05-20 15:20:00